# Slow and freezy 13.04 system under Nvidia graphics

Tags: drivers, nvidia, performance

I have the same problem under 13.04, I have Nvidia C73 (GeForce7100/nForce 630i) and it freezes randomly when I use Unity icons, the system is pretty slow anyway. I tried the opensource x-org driver, with the closed one it's much slower but not freezing. The kernel version is 3.8.0-19. Do you have any idea?

Thanks for your attention!

Comment: Are you sure your graphics card is the culprit? Maybe it is another cause. What are the specifications of your computer?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Nvidia driver.  It worked for me!  Go to Software & Updates, than Additional Drivers.  I chose the first option Using NVIDIA binary Xorg..... from nvidia-304

Comment: He/she said he/she already tried that